# subject-verb agreement when 'amount' is used

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

> Even a small amount of gases ***have*** / **has** a large effect.

This sentence is an exerpt from a reading passage, which is talking about CO2 in global warming. It says CO2 accounts for only 0.038% in the atmosphere, and then the example sentence 'Even a small amount of gases *have / has* a large effect.' appears.

- Which is the most appropriate answer?

  1. If **gases** is the subject, and it is plural, the correct answer would be 'have'.
  2. If the subject is **a small amount**, then the answer would be 'has'.

What do we see as the subject here? Can both be the subject?

Comment: @Chappo There is absolutely nothing wrong in asking for help with work on here so long as you clearly identify what aspect of the work is confusing you and causing you problems. Please delete your comment as it could mislead readers. Thanks.

Comment: @Chappo The comments above are correct. A proofreading question is a question like "please proofread the following paragraph". This question is not like that.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, MετάEd, Chappo: Shall we all delete our comments here?

Answer (score 2):

The subject can only be *amount*, since *gases* is part of a prepositional phrase describing *amount*. The number of the verb's going to follow the number of the subject, hence it should be singular *has*.

Comment: Correct. The key point is that the object of a preposition is never the subject of a sentence. The verb must match the subject.

Comment: @MετάEd *Almost* never, because there are troublesome beasts like *a number of* to prove the rule.

Comment: @Araucaria Thank you for your answer. And your example 'a number of~' was the very thing that I was wondering about. Could you tell me what makes the difference between the two? Or should I just understand the case 'a number of ~' as an idiom? Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: When it comes to phrases with the word *number*, the rule is that *the number* is always *singular*, while *a number* is always *plural*.

Comment: Sorry, VCCine, I'm mega-busy right now (I''m in trouble!), but maybe @MετάEd will help you with this one :) [nudge, nudge MετάEd!]

Comment: @Nick Yes +1 :) Nice point.

Answer (score 0):

In written English, the formal subject of the sentence (here, *amount*) will almost always be referenced and grammatical agreement/concord requires *has*.

The same is true for spoken English. However, it is possible that some speakers might say *have* because of the proximity of the word *gases*. This does not make *gases* the subject.

In short, use *has*.